# Paypal IPN sandbox test

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment

in  my IPN script I am using a variable called num_of_items. I use it for a loop to loop thru each item to make sure the cost and price paid are correct.

the problem is that my IPN works great when I directly use the GET method. However, when I use the POST method and then test via paypal's sandbox ipn simulator it won't pass this value  to my script. So, my script doesn't put anything into the database.

I would like to know how I can test my IPN script via the IPN simulator to pass in this variable?

Comment: I meant using: num_cart_items

Comment: Have you tried running an actual transaction on the sandbox instead of using the simulator?  that way you can add as many items as you need and actually replicate a real order.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and now everything works. The problem I have now is that If I have let's say 5 items in my cart. the IPN simulator only allows me to test for only 1 item in the cart. So, I cannot test to see if all different items in the cart will fire any errors. My PHP IPN script uses a loop to check each item in the cart. I the validates the prices for each cart and recalculates the total. It checks if the total matches. This is to avoid price fixing or manipulation. However, I have it to check for each item I sell with the use of regular expressions.I then checks the right database for it.

Comment: Well, again, if you run it in the actual sandbox (not using the simulator) you'll get exactly what you would from the live server so you can test it fully.  You could also build your own simulator and include all the params you need, with whatever data you want to test with.  Keep in mind if you do that the data isn't coming from PayPal's server so the verification in your IPN script would fail.

Comment: What's the difference between h sandbox and the simulator?  will the sandbox still send an IPN? I was told no and that I need to use the IPN simulator to test my IPN script.

Comment: The sandbox is the full, mirrored copy of the PayPal live servers.  You can setup buttons, integrate with it, and run through complete checkout flows to see exactly how everything works from both buyer and seller sides.  Yes, sandbox transactions will trigger IPN's as long as you have it configured on the seller account accordingly, so it can be used to more thoroughly test solutions.